# How do non-integral constants work in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, linkage, c++98

So I know that in C++ constants get, by default, different linkage than variables. That's why I must not put

```
int foo;
```

in some header – the linker will rightly complain about [multiple definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719). OTOH, I can write

```
const int bar = 42;
```

in a header, and the compiler makes sure there's only one definition of `bar`.

With integral constants, it is easy to see how the compiler deals with this – at least as long as nobody takes the address of `bar` or does some other funny thing requiring it to assign storage for it). However, what if someone does? And what if it isn't an integral but something that needs code to be executed at runtime? Assume I put this into a header:

```
const std::string baz = "h2g2";
```

Assuming no small string optimizations, this needs to allocate dynamic memory at runtime, so code needs to be executed, the address needs to be stored somewhere, etc.

I assume I would then end up with one definitions of `baz` per translation unit, only that the compiler assigns internal linkage to it to prevent the linker from complaining? Or am I missing something?

*Note:* I am ***not interested in `constexpr`***, just in plain old C++ constants, as they existed since the 80s and were codified in C++98. (However, if a comprehensive answer would include how this all fits together with **`constexpr`**, I wouldn't complain about that.)

Comment: You mean constants of non-primitive type. Floating point constants work the same way as integer constants.

Comment: @TemplateRex: I've added note explaining this.

Comment: @JasonS: Well, not exactly - they can't be Integral Constant Expressions for instance.

Comment: "the compiler makes sure there's only one definition of `bar`" - no it doesn't. It gives it internal linkage (as if you'd declared it `static`), so that it can be multiply defined.

Comment: @Mike TTBOMK, compilers can eliminate integral constants and use them as if they were literals.

Comment: @sbi: Indeed, if they're not odr-used. But that's got nothing to do with what I said; they're still defined in each translation unit that includes the definition, whether or not they're actually assigned storage.

Comment: @Mike. _In practice,_ most integral constants will very likely just evaporate. And I was asking about what happens if they can _not_ for whatever reasons, or if they cannot because they aren't integrals.

Comment: @sbi: As I said, and as the answer explains, it has internal linkage (as if you'd declared it static), so that it can be multiply defined. I was just trying to correct your misapprehension that there would be only one definition, but it looks like I inadvertently created more confusion instead. Sorry.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: what's "odr-used"?

Comment: @JasonS: Basically, used in such a way that it needs a definition (e.g. taking its address). The full definition is rather complicated; see section 3.2 of the C++ standard, if you want the gory details. "odr" stands for "one definition rule", which is the rule determining when and how things need to be defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring an object (at namespace scope) as `const` in C++ assigns it internal linkage by default.

If you declare (and define because of the initialization)

```
const std::string baz = "h2g2";
```

into a header you will have a statically linked string per each translation unit. The address would have to be stored in each translation unit (different addresses per different non-heap stored char literals - read only memory)

Edit: As a C++11 digression `constexpr` implies `const` since it means "*suitable for constant expressions evaluation*", thus it should have internal linkage as well. [Nb. [I'm not mentioning C++14]](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/)

Comment: SSO (Small String Optimization) applies to the content of `baz`, not the string literal. Your last sentence appears to confuse the two; SSO cannot affect the `char[]` literals

Comment: @sbi in this case no SSO should happen because the data is a char literal whose address is known at compile time

Comment: @Marco note the "`constexpr` implies `const`" part [is untrue in C++14](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/) and thus should nog be relied on.

Comment: Thanks ruben, I'll add this to the answer in case someone doesn't see your comment

Comment: However, note that "`constexpr` implies `const`" is indeed true for variables, even in C++14.